# Numbers logarithmically spaced between two floats in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get 1000 numbers logarithmically spaced between two floats (say between 0.674 to 100.0) using python. Purpose of this was to get more numbers closer to 0.674 and after than just few large numbers near 100. I tried using '*numpy.logspace*' function like following

`NumberRange = np.logspace(0.674, 100.0, num=1000)`

But it was giving result with these numbers as exponents. I want numbers between two floats but spaced logarithmically.

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418234/logarithmically-spaced-integers) post but it was confusing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The first two arguments of [`numpy.logspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) are the *exponents* of the limits.  Use

```
NumberRange = np.logspace(np.log10(0.674), np.log10(100.0), num=1000)
```

Recent versions of NumPy have the function [`geomspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html), which takes the values of the endpoints rather than their logarithms:

```
NumberRange = np.geomspace(0.674, 100.0, num=1000)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how to do this if you want points on log scale from 0 to 1 (including 0)? Is it possible ?

Comment: log(0) is undefined, you can draw an arrow to represent -inf